# Find words sequence in a document

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm

Using Java (on Android) I try to find a way (fast one...) to resolve this problem :

I have a list of words (around 10 to 30) and a document. The length of the document can vary too, maybe around 2500 to 10000 words. This document is part of a book.

The thing i want is to find in this document the string (sentence...) who contains the higher quantity of the words in my list. The words in the document has to be in the same order as my words list. Normally the words should not be so far one from the other in the document, maybe max 2 or 3 words between each words of my list.

To be more clear, lets take an example with small data.

My word list is :

> harm piece work day

my document :

> just so, with the greatest care.  You must see to it that you pull up
>   regularly all the baobabs, at the very first moment when they can be
>   distinguished from the rosebushes which they resemble so closely in
>   their earliest youth.  It is very tedious work," the little prince
>   added, "but very easy."   And one day he said to me: "You ought to
>   make a beautiful drawing, so that the children where you live can see
>   exactly how all this is.  That would be very useful to them if they
>   were to travel some day.  Sometimes," he added, "there is no **harm**
>   in putting off a **piece** of **work** until another **day**.  But
>   when it is a matter of baobabs, that always means a catastrophe.  I
>   knew a planet that was inhabited by a lazy man.  He neglected three
>   little bushes..."   So, as the little prince described it to me, I
>   have made a drawing of that planet.  I do not much like to take the
>   tone of a moralist.  But the danger of the baobabs is so little
>   understood, and such considerable risks would be run by anyone who
>   might get lost on an asteroid, that for once I am breaking through my
>   reserve.  "Children," I say plainly, "watch out for the baobabs!"

The goal is to find the string "there is no harm in putting off a piece of work until another day" in the document.

For now, the only way i think about is :

1 - find the first occurrence of the first word in my list in the document.

2 - multiply the number of words in my list by 2 or 3 to get the string length i have to check in my document (regarding the max number of words between the words of my list in the document).

3 - search for the occurrence of the other words in my list in this document string (having the string length I got in step 2) by split and loop.

If I consider the occurrence of my words in this string is not enough (maybe around 50%) then continu searching in the document starting by the next occurrence of the first word in my list.

But I'm afraid this could be very long, too much long, specially because I'm working on a mobile device... So i'm here to grab some ideas I maybe didn't think about, or some libs who could help me with this task. I thought about regular expressions too but I'm not sure if it would be a better way.

> @gukoff proposition

Regarding that finally my words list can't be in a different order than my text it simplify the algorithm. The beginning of @gukoff answer is enough. No need to implement the LIS algorithm or reverse the list.

```
//Section = input text
//wordsToFind = words to find in text separated by space
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test1(String wordsToFind, Section section) {
    //1. Create the index of your words array.
    String[] wordsArray = wordsToFind.split(" ");

    ArrayList<Integer> indexesSentences = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> sentenceArrayIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> wordsToFindIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Sentence sentence:section.getSentences()) {
        indexesSentences.clear();
        for(String sentenceWord:sentence.getWords()) {
            wordsToFindIndexes.clear();
            int j = 0;
            for(String word:wordsArray) {
                if(word.equals(sentenceWord)) {
                    wordsToFindIndexes.add(j+1);
                }
                j++;
            }
            //Collections.reverse(wordsToFindIndexes);
            for(int idx:wordsToFindIndexes) {
                indexesSentences.add(idx);
            }
        }
        sentenceArrayIndexes.add((ArrayList<Integer>)indexesSentences.clone());
    }
    return sentenceArrayIndexes;
}

public class Section {
    private ArrayList<Sentence> sentences;

    public Section (String text) {
        sentences = new ArrayList<>();

        if(text == null || text.trim() == "") {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Text not valid");
        }
        String formattedText = text.trim().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z. ]", "").toLowerCase();
        String[] sentencesArray = formattedText.split("\\.");
        for(String sentenceStr:sentencesArray) {
            if(sentenceStr.trim() != "") {
                sentences.add(new Sentence(sentenceStr));
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Sentence> getSentences() {
        return sentences;
    }

    public void addSentence(Sentence sentence) {
        sentences.add(sentence);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have the words to be found and a text, which consists of sentences to be examined.

1. Create the index of your words array.

For example, if `words` = `a dog is not a human`:

```
{
    "a": [1, 5],
    "dog": [2],
    "is": [3],
    "not": [4],
    "human": [6]
}
```

2. In every sentence replace every word by its index value in **descending** order. That said, `"a"` gets replaced by `[5, 1]`, `"human"` gets replaced by `[6]` and `"tree"` gets replaced by `[]`.

For example, the sentence `"not a cat is a human"` should turn into `[4, 5,1, 3, 5,1, 6]`

3. Find the [Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)(LIS) in every array. Essentially, LIS would be the longest sub-match of your words array in the sentence.

For example, LIS of `[4, 5,1, 3, 5,1, 6]`  is `[1, 3, 5, 6]`, which maps to the sub-match `"a is a human"`.

But generally, in case the words shouldn't be very far from each other, I suggest to find LIS using dynamic programming with corresponding modifications.

Comment: After going deeper in this subject it looks like the input data can't have matching words in a different order than my words to find list. So it's simplify a lot the algorithm. I don't have to reverse the indexes in descending order, the beginning of your solution is enough and I don't need to use the LIS algorithm. I have an array of all my sentences and for every sentences the index of my words in my words array. Actually counting the words to find for every sentence and keep the sentence index in my text would be enough. Anyway It gave me an idea for another feature in my app so I keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach which should be good enough given your document size:

1. make an `array` (call it `words`) of size `n` where `n` is number of words in your `document`.
2. Now populate this array such that
    `words[i] = 0` if no words in your `list` match this word
    `words[i] = k` if `kth` word in your `list` matches this word (`1` based indexing )

   Example: If your document is `there is no harm in putting off a piece of work until another day.` and word list is `work day harm piece` (in that order) then your `words`array will look like this `[0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,1,0,0,2]`

2.Now you will have an array of size `2000~3000` of integers.You can use a variant of [Longest common subsequence problem](http://Longest%20common%20subsequence%20problem) or modify your algorithm a little to find the best match.

Comment: Started to try your solution. I'm not sure I understood correctly the part "words[i] = k if kth word in your list matches this word (1 based indexing )". For now i'm at the point before using the "Longest common subsequence problem". I edited my question with the title **@xashru proposition Update #1** because the comment form size is too short to put my code. Does it looks like what you proposed in your answer for now ?